# Can I do RGBD-6D-SLAM on an empty room?

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, rgbd6dslam, rgbd-slam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As I know RGBD-6D-SLAM uses surf feature to do the job, what if the room I'm going to reconstruct is empty and thus featureless.
Can RGBD-6D-SLAM still able to reconstruct it ?
Thank!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63506/can-i-do-rgbd-6d-slam-on-an-empty-room-?/) by [Benzwr](https://answers.ros.org/users/4977/benzwr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2013-05-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

it depends, if something is completely featureless it is not possible to reconstruct it even for a human. I have worked in pretty empty environments and sometimes it is enough with the texture in the floor and walls. Anyway, you won't probably get very good results. I am talking from my experience

---

Originally posted by [Kailegh](https://answers.ros.org/users/21460/kailegh/) with karma: 146 on 2017-06-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1